# Close MySQL execute() query in Java

Tags: java, mysql

Okay, so I have the following code:

```
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            boolean resultSet = statement.execute("INSERT INTO guilds(`ID`, `Prefix`, `Join`, `Leave`, `EnableRoles`, `Role`)" 
                +"select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6"
                +"from (select '"+id+"' as col1, '//' as col2, 'Welcome, {user}!' as col3, 'Goodbye, {user}!' as col4, 'false' as col5, 'none' as col6) t"
                +"WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM guilds WHERE ID = '123');");
```

Usually, when you do executeQuery(); you have a resultSet.close(); method.

I was wondering if there is one for execute() (didn't seem to pop up on IDE) and if not, if/how you close it like resultSet.close();

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just close the statement `statement.close()`;

Also it would be good to place everything in `try` `catch` block and perform closing in `finally` clause.

Comment: Now I have another problem, the query I am using works in SQL (workbench, whatever) but not in Java? What is causing this?

_com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select '215406250656137216' as col1, '//' as col2, 'Welcome!' as col3, 'Goodbye!' at line 1_

Comment: @Arraying may be you should create another question. I am not quite familiar with mysql syntax. However, you are using 2 different single quote characters (look what you are using inside insert and what you are using inside select) ... may that is a problem.

Comment: I can't create a new question since i have to wait, and yes, that's the way it's supposed to be I believe.

Comment: @Arraying O.k. Also leave some *spaces* before `select`, `from`, `where` you are putting them too close to each other inside the string...  And may be the internal select must be inside parenthesis ? `()`